# Write Spark data frame to multiple s3 buckets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to save dataframe rows in the different S3 buckets. Let's assume all buckets exist.
I have a simple dataframe:

| tenantId | charge |
| --- | --- |
| tenant1 | 10 |
| tenant2 | 20 |

I want to partition data by tenantId, but the tricky point is that each tenant data should be stored in a different bucket.
I can split the dataframe into many and store each of them independently, i.e. call save(...) method on each of them. However, for the performance reason, it will be a terrible solution. Is there any better?

Thanks

Comment: You can partition your data by tenantId and save it in the same S3 bucket. It will create subfolders for each tenantId and in that way you can keep your data separate for each tenantId unless you have any specific reason to store it on different S3 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `partitionBy` clause as -

```
          df.write.
          partitionBy("tenantId").
          parquet("the root path")
```

It will create distinct folder by names "tenant1" and "tenant2" and put respective rows inside.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I'm asking about multi-bucket. I know I can partition data in the same bucket. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

different s3 buckets? Afraid not. way too complicated. The spark DF code assumes that everything is in the same filesystem with things like rename() spanning them; even the zero-rename committers all assume its the same destination bucket.

If you do write to a single bucket, you can use the `aws s3 copy` command to copy data from that single bucket into tenant-specific buckets. It will do that copy within S3 so is faster than doing it locally -and it will allow you to copy different tenant's data simultaneously just by spawning a different copy process for each tenant

Comment: The problem is that I use Delta Lake under the hood, so s3 copy could not help me. Am I right?

Comment: you don't want to try and move stuff around under the hood of any of the table formats which don't use directory listings to find source files. You'll have to talk to the relevant project